# expect script, spawn multiple processes(closed)

Tags: git, expect, spawn

The idea is very simple, using an expect script to push a git local repo to github

```
#! /usr/bin/expect -f
spawn git add -A 
spawn git commit -m 'server auto update' 
spawn git push
expect "Username for 'https://github.com':"
send <username\r>
expect "Password for 'https://xxxx@github.com':"
send <password\r>
```

I think my question could be more accurate: how to spawn multiple processes, since I tested the script with only git push, it works, so I guess the multiple spawn I have in my code is the problem.

Current Solution: 
I wrote another bash script to automate the add and commit job for me and at the end of the bash script I call the expect script.

Better solution(tested and works)

```
exec git add -A 
execute git commit -m ""
```

Comment: You appear to be writing an expect script, not a bash script. Replace the shebang with `#!/usr/bin/expect -f`.

Comment: You also generate ssh-key and add to github. So you do not need type password

Comment: @4ae1e1, I did what you suggested as #!/usr/bin/expect -f, now the error is invalid command name "git "

Comment: You need to `spawn` commands in expect.

Comment: @4ae1e1 Thank you very much

Comment: @NguyenSyThanhSon, I have not tried your method, but thank you

Comment: @4ae1e1, github could accept my authentications now but I dont think the push was successful. The spawn I used is probably not correct.

Comment: @MohanL I have no time to test now, sorry. Also, I only know a bare minimum of expect, so you might need to wait for an expert.

Comment: @4ae1e1, Thank you very much, I think my question could be more accurate: how to spawn multiple processes, since I tested the script with only git push, it works, so I guess the multiple spawn I have in my code is the problem.

Comment: What about `exec git add -A` and `exec git command -m 'whatever'`?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're not generating an SSH key and just use `git push` to be done with it?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of going this roundabout way, **[Generate an SSH key and register it with GitHub](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/)**, GitHub won't ask for your password (unless you generate the key with a passphrase) when you push, and it's considered more secure than a password (as long as your private key actually remains private).

See the linked article for more details.

Answer (score 0):

this code is working for me

```js
spawn git push
set timeout 300

expect "Username*:" {
        send "userName\n"
        expect  "Password" {
            send "Pasword\n"
        }
        
}

expect eof
```