# Bash: Forward keyboard input to background program?

Tags: bash, keyboard, tty, subshell

I have a bash script where I spawn a program in a subshell and wait for it to finish:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -m
(
  theprogram & echo $! > "${PROGRAM_PID}"
)
set +m

tail --pid "$(cat "${PROGRAM_PID}")" --follow /dev/null & wait $!
```

The problem is that when the users presses any keys, they are not received by that program. I suppose this is caused by the fact that its running in a different process.

So is there any way to redirect all keyboard input to this PID?

Comment: It's because the program runs in the background (caused by the `&`). Read "Job Control" in `man bash`.

Comment: @choroba Yes I already suspected that, but I need it to stay in the background. So is there any way how I can forward all keypresses to this backgrounded program?

Comment: Maybe you could do it with expect e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77144806/in-expect-how-can-i-interact-with-multiple-spawned-processes? I think that generally when you run something in the background you don't want to interact with it, so not sure if there's a 'simple' solution sorry

Comment: From the bash manual: "Background processes which attempt to read from (write to) the terminal are sent a SIGTTIN (SIGTTOU) signal by the terminal driver, which, unless caught, suspends the process." So I think you need to foreground it, and have `tail` in the background instead.

Comment: Can you start `theprogram` in another terminal like : `xterm -e theprogram` ?

Comment: That sounds awfully like a XY problem. A feeling reinforced by some rube-goldberg machinery, like `echo $! > ${var}`...`"$(cat "${var}")"`, or `tail --pid $pid -f /dev/null & wait $!` (why not just wait for the pid itself rather than lauching a tail whose whole purpose is only to die when theprogram die, and wait for that tail?)

Comment: So, in other words, before we help you build another rube-goldberg machine: what are you really trying to do? Can you describe some context? What that program does, why do you need to run it in the foreground while interacting with it?

Comment: If I understood correctly, you want to run `theprogram` and want its PID written in a file. Then, you can just run `theprogram &`, `echo $! > file`, and `fg`.

Comment: How is the background program written, i.e. where does it expect the input coming from? Does it poll for input? After all, it is running asynchrounasly. What is the expected behaviour, if the user presses a key, and the program is already terminated?

Comment: @chrslg The reason I cannot wait on the PID without tail is that its not a child process (because of the set -m line). I agree its a bit strange code, but the program that I launch is QEMU and I need to trap the stop signals so I can shutdown the guest OS gracefully. The set -m line is so that QEMU does not receive any stop signals that the parent script receives, otherwise they would trickle down. This solution is working great except for the missing keyboard input.

Comment: @user1934428 The background program is QEMU and it boots Alpine (or any other OS) and shows its terminal. If I launch it in the foreground it will receive the key presses, but if I launch it in the background it won't. The reason why I need to launch it in the background is so I can I intercept the stop signals (see previous reply). So yes its a bit of a XY problem, I just hoped there would be a simple way to allow for keyboard input.

Comment: This does not answer how it accepts its input. If QEMU for instance insists of receiving the input from a real "terminal", it will find that in the background, there is no terminal available, and simply would not even look for keyboard input. In this case, I guess that the first step would be to start QEMU in an environment, where it has a [PTY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoterminal) allocated.  If it however accepts the input via stdin, you can feed it through a pipe, but the idea of a "keypress" of course does not make sense then.

Comment: I don't know whether it will work, but maybe `expect` can be used to control QEMU. The idea would be that you run `expect` in the background as well (together with QEMU), but your expect- program, which you can design by yourself, could by some means (for instance, via a socket), fetch the keystrokes. This means that you have to write two programs: One running in foreground, which receives the input from the user and sends it to the (i.e.) socket, and the expect-program which runs in the background, fetches the input from the socket and uses it to drive QEMU.

Comment: For `expect`, see here: https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Expect